Why is my laptop "randomly" rebooting after fresh install of Windows 11 Pro?
I'd like to get some tips on identify what is causing my laptop to reboot randomly and multiple times per day.
Acer Nitro AN515-57

i7 11800H
3060M
16GB
1TB NVMe
Windows 11 Pro

I tried looking into event viewer but I can't tell what exactly is.
chkdsk no error
sfc /scannow fixed these
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\BthA2dp.sys
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\BthHfEnum.sys
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\bthmodem.sys

DISM repair successful

Drivers are up to date with SDIO
did all latest win updates. CPU is under-volted but reboots also happen when CPU running normally.

We MAY be able to read between the lines a little bit, but given the possible range of actions people may take prior to encountering problems and asking here: don't assume WE'RE the unreasonable ones for failing to infer what you are implying. Don't make us infer, don't imply: Tell us clearly what you need to tell us, so that we can clearly understand YOUR situation and need, and hopefully get you a good answer.

Further, we need to know what files were fixed by SFC, we also need to know if you ran DISM afterwards, we need to know the patch level of Windows, we need to know more clearly what you did or didn't find in Event Viewer (or, if you don't understand what you're seeing in there and don't know what to look for or how to look for it). It's OK not to know: we just need to know what it is you need to learn, so you, at least, need to know what it is you do not know.

Repaired file:
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\BthA2dp.sys
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\BthHfEnum.sys
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\bthmodem.sys
pretty sure it said it fixed 4 files but only these 3 are listed in the log

Please add all that info to your main question. I recommend that you spend some time reviewing the Help section. It is a good guide for understanding how this site works, what makes it unique from a more general Forum.


Was it randomly crashing before reinstalling Windows? 2) What is the make and model of the laptop? It could be something like a pin on a RAM socket having come loose from flexing of the motherboard.


hello, no the pc never had random reboots, the laptop model is AN515-57 from Acer.
I did run MEMTEST and showed no errors

The "bth" at the start of those filenames is likely to be for Bluetooth; you can download the latest driver from this Intel page, if you want to reinstall them to see if that makes a difference.

Music2myear asked if you'd found anything in Windows Event Viewer. There might be something useful from just before the crash in either the Application or System event logs.
